# How to print the entire contents of a sent mail for debug purposes?

Tags: postfix, mail-command

I try to see the raw data of a mail that I sent with `mail -s "My Subject" me@example.org`.

Is it possible, if so, how?

Expected output is similar to:

```
From: "root" <root@example.org>
To: me@example.org
Subject: My Subject
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

My Body
```

Answer (score 0):

`mailq` or `postqueue -p` will show my queue (incl. my rejected mail). I can pass that identifier to `postcat -q $ID` to see the raw message.